# Why doesn't openssl from Homebrew include aes-256-gcm cipher support?

Tags: openssl

I have installed latest `openssl` via Homebrew on my Mac (macOS Big Sur 11.5.2). But it doesn't support `aes-256-gcm` cipher suddenly.

```
$ /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl enc -ciphers | grep aes-
-aes-128-cbc               -aes-128-cfb               -aes-128-cfb1
-aes-128-cfb8              -aes-128-ctr               -aes-128-ecb
-aes-128-ofb               -aes-192-cbc               -aes-192-cfb
-aes-192-cfb1              -aes-192-cfb8              -aes-192-ctr
-aes-192-ecb               -aes-192-ofb               -aes-256-cbc
-aes-256-cfb               -aes-256-cfb1              -aes-256-cfb8
-aes-256-ctr               -aes-256-ecb               -aes-256-ofb
```

```
$ /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
```

How can I enable the cipher? And why isn't it included in the package?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic: We do not provide end user support. You may be able to get help on one of our sister sites such as [apple.se], [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 2):

I've found the reason of my issue. It is described in the [openssl docs](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/14d3bb06c9c11b3e13c64611913757c27bc057f2/doc/man1/openssl-enc.pod.in#L268).

> This command does not support authenticated encryption modes
> like CCM and GCM, and will not support such modes in the future.
> This is due to having to begin streaming output (e.g., to standard output
> when **-out** is not used) before the authentication tag could be validated.
> When this command is used in a pipeline, the receiving end will not be
> able to roll back upon authentication failure.  The AEAD modes currently in
> common use also suffer from catastrophic failure of confidentiality and/or
> integrity upon reuse of key/iv/nonce, and since **openssl enc** places the
> entire burden of key/iv/nonce management upon the user, the risk of
> exposing AEAD modes is too great to allow.  These key/iv/nonce
> management issues also affect other modes currently exposed in this command,
> but the failure modes are less extreme in these cases, and the
> functionality cannot be removed with a stable release branch.